# Sort table not sorting input

Tags: javascript, html

How can I sort the following table I used `var rows = $('#mytable tbody tr').get();` should I also include the div and the span and input inorder for it to work? The sort is not working

HTML

```
<table id="mytable" class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th id="employee" class="col-xs-2">Employee</th>
                    <th id="basic_pay" style="color:#337ab7;">basic pay</th>
                    <th id="tax" style="color:#337ab7;">tax</th>
                    <th id="loans" style="color:#337ab7;">loans</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <% @pay_list.each do |a| %>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%= a.user.profile.full_name %></td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">₱</span>
                                <input value="12000.0" class="form-control 
                                 currency" id="display_basic_pay_4">
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" id="child_num_<%= a.id %>" value="<%= a.user.profile.num_of_children%>" />
                        </td>
                            <td>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">₱</span>
                                <input value="12000.0" class="form-control 
                                 currency" id="display_basic_pay_4">
                            </div></td>
                        <% end %>
                    </tr>
                <% end %>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
function sortTable(f,n){
    var rows = $('#mytable tbody tr').get();
    rows.sort(function(a, b) {
        var A = getVal(a);
        var B = getVal(b);
        if(A < B) {
            return -1*f;
        }
        if(A > B) {
            return 1*f;
        }
        return 0;
    });
    function getVal(elm){
        var v = $(elm).children('td').eq(n).text().toUpperCase();
        if($.isNumeric(v)){
            v = parseInt(v,10);
        }
        return v;
    }
    $.each(rows, function(index, row) {
        $('#mytable').children('tbody').append(row);
    });
}

var f_basic_pay = 1;
var f_tax = 1;
$("#basic_pay").click(function(){
    f_basic_pay *= -1;
    var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
    sortTable(f_basic_pay,n);
});
$("#tax").click(function(){
    f_tax *= -1;
    var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
    sortTable(f_tax,n);
});
```

Used rails for the <% values %>

Comment: What's the problem with your existing script ?

Comment: @GGO the sort is working but its not sorting the value when its inside the div and span but when use place in just a  <tr><td>Value<td><tr> it sorts the value

Comment: Ok you want to sort table by this value : `<span class="input-group-addon">₱</span>` ? What's `₱` ? can we see html output instead of server side code ?

Comment: @GGO i want to sort <input value="12000.0" the 12000.0 is the value displayed i will try to put the html output

Comment: you are trying to get the full text() of the cell, try targeting the value in the input field if that is what you want to sort by. See my answer on how to retrieve the values.

Comment: @John Is your problem solved ? Feel free to accept the best answer to close topic thks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Looking to the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/text/), the function
>   `$.text()` will returns all combined text
>   contents. That means, it's an equivalent of `.html()` but combining all tag
>   childrens.

What you want to do is sorting by a html attribute value : `<input value="12000.0" ...`, and `text()` can't read them. 
You can use instead :

```
function getVal(elm){
    var v = $(elm).children('td input.currency').eq(n).val().toUpperCase();
    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a css class to the input fields in your cells and updated your getVal() method to retrieve this value for comparison. Check below snippet:

```js
function sortTable(f,n){
    var rows = $('#mytable tbody tr').get();
    
    rows.sort(function(a, b) {
        var A = getVal(a);
        var B = getVal(b);
       
        if(A < B) {
            return -1*f;
        }
        if(A > B) {
            return 1*f;
        }
        return 0;
    });
    function getVal(elm){
        var element = $(elm).children('td').get(n);
        
        var v = $(".sort_val",element).val()
        if($.isNumeric(v)){
            v = parseInt(v,10);
        }
        
        return v;
    }
    $.each(rows, function(index, row) {
        $('#mytable').children('tbody').append(row);
    });
}

var f_basic_pay = 1;
var f_tax = 1;
$("#basic_pay").click(function(){
    f_basic_pay *= -1;
    var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
   
    sortTable(f_basic_pay,n);
});
$("#tax").click(function(){
    f_tax *= -1;
    var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
    sortTable(f_tax,n);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable" class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th id="employee" class="col-xs-2">Employee</th>
                    <th id="basic_pay" style="color:#337ab7;">basic pay</th>
                    <th id="tax" style="color:#337ab7;">tax</th>
                    <th id="sss" style="color:#337ab7;">sss</th>
                    <th id="hdmf" style="color:#337ab7;">hdmf</th>
                    <th id="phil_health" style="color:#337ab7;">phil_health</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                
                    <tr>
                        <td>  User 1 </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">₱</span>
                                <input value="14000.0" class="form-control 
                                 currency sort_val" id="display_basic_pay_14">
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" id="child_num_14" value="14" />
                        </td>
                            <td>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">₱</span>
                                <input value="14000.0" class="form-control 
                                 currency sort_val" id="display_basic_pay_4">
                            </div></td>
                       
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>  User 2 </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">₱</span>
                                <input value="12000.0" class="form-control 
                                 currency sort_val" id="display_basic_pay_4">
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" id="child_num_12" value="12" />
                        </td>
                            <td>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">₱</span>
                                <input value="12000.0" class="form-control 
                                 currency sort_val" id="display_basic_pay_4">
                            </div></td>
                       
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>  User 3 </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">₱</span>
                                <input value="15000.0" class="form-control 
                                 currency sort_val" id="display_basic_pay_4">
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" id="child_num_15" value="15" />
                        </td>
                            <td>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">₱</span>
                                <input value="15000.0" class="form-control 
                                 currency sort_val" id="display_basic_pay_4">
                            </div></td>
                       
                    </tr>
               
            </tbody>
        </table>
```